# Does Glimpse work with Linq2SQL natively or do I need a plugin?

Tags: linq-to-sql, glimpse

I see there is a special plugin for Entity Framework, do I need anything for Linq2SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin written for Linq2Sql too:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/FlexLabs.Glimpse.Linq2Sql

`Install-Package FlexLabs.Glimpse.Linq2Sql`